# R Function to write 3 calculated columns to a data.table

Tags: r, function, data.table

This may have already been answered, but couldn't quite find the answer I am looking for. I am trying to write the output of a function that calculates 3 variables to a data.table.

Currently I am copying the function three times (with three different names), each time returning a different variable. This is taking a lot more time as it runs thrice. I understand
there may be a better way to do it, using list or some unique `data.table` command.

I would greatly appreciate any input you can provide to simplify this. Below is the example of how I am calling it one variable at a time.

## Example

```
  fn_1 <- function(a, b, c, d){
    
    for (i in 1:b) { col_1[i] = calculation }
    for (i in 1:c) { col_2[i] = calculation }
    for (i in 1:d) { col_3[i] = calculation }

    return(col_1)
  }
  
  data[ ,column_1 := fn_1(a,b,c,d) ,by= .(e,f) ]


  fn_2 <- function(a, b, c, d){
    
    for (i in 1:b) { col_1[i] = calculation }
    for (i in 1:c) { col_2[i] = calculation }
    for (i in 1:d) { col_3[i] = calculation }

    return(col_2)
  }
  
  data[ ,column_2 := fn_2(a,b,c,d) ,by= .(e,f) ]
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: General advice: use a function that returns a list of 3 (or n) outputs, and assign it to 3 (n) new columns in a vector as in `data[, c("a","b","c") := fun_w_3_outputs(...)]`

Comment: The way, the `for` loops inside the function definition are used indicate that the results of calculating `col_1`, `col_2`, and `col_3` might have different lengths of `b`, `c`, and `d`, resp.Is this intendend?

Answer (score 2):

The OP has tagged the question with `data.table`. [docendo discimus' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390567/r-function-to-write-3-calculated-columns-to-a-data-table#comment75781285_44390567) is showing the direction to follow.

#### Create sample data

```
library(data.table)   # CRAN version 1.10.4 used

n <- 10L
DT <- data.table(
  a = 1:n, b = (n:1)^2, c = -(1:n), d = 2 * (1:n) - n/2,
  e = rep(LETTERS[1:2], length.out = n), 
  f = rep(LETTERS[3:4], each = n/2, length.out = n))
DT  
#     a   b   c  d e f
# 1:  1 100  -1 -3 A C
# 2:  2  81  -2 -1 B C
# 3:  3  64  -3  1 A C
# 4:  4  49  -4  3 B C
# 5:  5  36  -5  5 A C
# 6:  6  25  -6  7 B D
# 7:  7  16  -7  9 A D
# 8:  8   9  -8 11 B D
# 9:  9   4  -9 13 A D
#10: 10   1 -10 15 B D
```

#### Define function

```
fn <- function(p, q, r, s) {
  list(X1 = p + mean(q) + r + s,
       Y2 = p * q + r * s,
       Z3 = p * q - r * s)
}
```

The function takes 4 parameters and returns a list of 3 named vectors. Note that the computations inside the function don't need to use `for` loops in contrast to OP's approach.

#### Apply function to data.table

Note that the OP wants to group on columns `e` and `f` when the function is applied.

The first variant creates a new data.table. By default, the names of the list elements as defined in `fn` are used:

```
DT[, fn(a, b, c, d), .(e, f)]
#    e f       X1   Y2  Z3
# 1: A C 63.66667  103  97
# 2: A C 67.66667  189 195
# 3: A C 71.66667  155 205
# 4: B C 64.00000  164 160
# 5: B C 68.00000  184 208
# 6: B D 18.66667  108 192
# 7: B D 22.66667  -16 160
# 8: B D 26.66667 -140 160
# 9: A D 19.00000   49 175
#10: A D 23.00000  -81 153
```

The second variant updates `DT` *by reference*. The names of the new columns are explicitely stated.

```
DT[, c("x", "y", "z") := fn(a, b, c, d), .(e, f)]

DT
#     a   b   c  d e f        x    y   z
# 1:  1 100  -1 -3 A C 63.66667  103  97
# 2:  2  81  -2 -1 B C 64.00000  164 160
# 3:  3  64  -3  1 A C 67.66667  189 195
# 4:  4  49  -4  3 B C 68.00000  184 208
# 5:  5  36  -5  5 A C 71.66667  155 205
# 6:  6  25  -6  7 B D 18.66667  108 192
# 7:  7  16  -7  9 A D 19.00000   49 175
# 8:  8   9  -8 11 B D 22.66667  -16 160
# 9:  9   4  -9 13 A D 23.00000  -81 153
#10: 10   1 -10 15 B D 26.66667 -140 160
```

Answer (score 1):

You're in the [second circle of hell](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). To solve the problem, pre-allocate what you want to add.

```
data <- data.table(c(1, 2, 3), c(4, 5, 6), c(7, 8, 9))
```

Then, make a vectorized function to do the calculation, which returns the whole column to append.

```
calculation <- Vectorize(function(x) mean(c(x, 3)))
```

Write fn in terms of this new function, and return the whole block of columns to be added, then cbind it with `data` to add all the columns at once. It's extremely slow to do all the calculations every time, and then only return one part.

```
fn <- function(b, c, d) {
  toBeAdded <- data.table(matrix(nrow = nrow(data), ncol = 3))
  toBeAdded[ , 1] <- calculation(b)
  toBeAdded[ , 2] <- calculation(b)
  toBeAdded[ , 3] <- calculation(b)
  toBeAdded
}

data <- cbind(data, fn(data[1,], data[2,], data[3,]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, based on inputs from @docendodiscimus & @ConCave, i solved it like this. appreciate everyone's input!

```
  fn_1 <- function(a, b, c, d){

    for (i in 1:b) { col_1[i] = calculation }
    for (i in 1:c) { col_2[i] = calculation }
    for (i in 1:d) { col_3[i] = calculation }

      df = data.table(col_1, col_2, col_3)
      return(df)
  }

  data[,c("column_1","column_2","column_3"):= fn_1(a,b,c,d) ,by= .(e,f)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a data.table?  If not , then you can just use `mutate` in `dplyr`

```
a <- c(1,2,2,1,2,3,4,2)
b <- c(3,3,2,3,5,4,3,2)
c <- c(9,9,8,7,8,9,8,7)
d <- c(0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1)

have <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)

want <- 
  have %>% 
  mutate(abc = a+ b + c,
         db = d * b,
         aa = 2 * a)
```

Comment: Or you can just use `transform` from base R as in `transform(have, abc = a+ b + c, db = d * b, aa = 2 * a)` without loading unnecessary packages.